# Animation nodes - Driving scale attribute from a CSV list to create a bar chart

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

I'm stuck with the 'For Loop' part of my project in Animation Nodes.

I'm trying to create a bar chart with each of x bars scaled to a high set by some CSV data.  I've got my .blend and it feels so close but I can't make it work.

You'll see that I've created a cube and used the Object Instancer and a loop to create an array of x columns.  By putting the pivot point at the bottom of the cube I can scale on z axis give me the height of the bar chart.  This node tree ends with the scale attribute in the Object Attribute Output.

Below that node tree I have a Text Block Reader that splits the text (by lines) and then another split (by separator) to get my list which I hoped to use to drive the heights of the columns.  This is a string so I've used a node to convert to a float.

Now I'm way out my depth and I can't get the values from the list to drive the different heights of the bars.

Lastly, a nice to have only - If you do have a solution, is there a way to mix between 0 values for Z scale and the values from the CSV list so that I can key frame both and animate the bar chart rising?  That would be perfection.

Just a note that I've been able to get to a solution before by using the Python on Tamir Lousky's Github page but wanted to do it in Animation Nodes.

Many thanks to anyone who can help - this is beyond me but I'm trying to learn.

Blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hedqgdwqkh6evrf/animation_nodes3.blend?dl=0

Image of node tree:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kivegj9bm956rps/Nodetree.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your “parse” loop loops over the list of lines given by the *Split Text* node with mode set to lines. This is useful if your .csv file is in this form:

```
name, value
A, 1
B, 2
C, 3
```

But if your file is in the form of

```
A, B, C
1, 2, 3
```

then you'll have to

1. split the file into lines,
2. pick the line with the values in it,
3. split this line at the value separators *outside* of the loop
4. and then loop over the value strings.

[image: subtree for separating lines]

Depending on the number format of your values (e.g. decimal comma, thousands separator) you might have to use a *script node* to parse them. However, a simple *Parse Number* node might be enough for your file. The parsed number has to be piped into the loop's output that you can generate by clicking *New Generator Output* and choosing the type *Float List*.

[image: parse number loop]

Finally, the parsed list of numbers will be piped as an additional iterator into the other loop which is used to place and scale the bars (*New Iterator* > *Float List*). Using a *Vector from Value* node, piped into the *Object Transforms Ouput* is sufficient if you only enable scaling for the *Z* value, but you could also use a *Combine Vector* node:

[image: object loop]

If the number of columns in your .csv file is the same as the number of bars then you could also combine them into a single loop with one *Object List* iterator and one *String List* iterator. However, two loops offer more flexibility if the .csv file should contain a column header (or line header in your case) or when you want to select for which values you want to create a bar.

[image: combined into single loop]

Comment: Solution verified.  Renaming my loops helped get this straight in my mind and I also found the 'convert' node to change a text list into a float list.